# How to add Plotly multiple surfaces with a for loop in R

Tags: r, loops, plotly, surface

I am plotting multiple surfaces graphs in R. This is an example from the Plotly page:

```
z <- c(
  c(8.83,8.89,8.81,8.87,8.9,8.87),
  c(8.89,8.94,8.85,8.94,8.96,8.92),
  c(8.84,8.9,8.82,8.92,8.93,8.91),
  c(8.79,8.85,8.79,8.9,8.94,8.92),
  c(8.79,8.88,8.81,8.9,8.95,8.92),
  c(8.8,8.82,8.78,8.91,8.94,8.92),
  c(8.75,8.78,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.92),
  c(8.8,8.8,8.77,8.91,8.95,8.94),
  c(8.74,8.81,8.76,8.93,8.98,8.99),
  c(8.89,8.99,8.92,9.1,9.13,9.11),
  c(8.97,8.97,8.91,9.09,9.11,9.11),
  c(9.04,9.08,9.05,9.25,9.28,9.27),
  c(9,9.01,9,9.2,9.23,9.2),
  c(8.99,8.99,8.98,9.18,9.2,9.19),
  c(8.93,8.97,8.97,9.18,9.2,9.18)
)
dim(z) <- c(15,6)
z2 <- z + 1
z3 <- z - 1

fig <- plot_ly(showscale = FALSE)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z2, opacity = 0.98)
fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~z3, opacity = 0.98)

fig
```

You can watch the result here: https://plotly.com/r/3d-surface-plots/

I'm trying to do the same for a 3D numeric matrix with the following R code:

```
# Create a tridimensional array
R = 3

v1 = replicate(R, 0)
v2 = replicate(R, 0)
v3 = replicate(R, 0)

AR <- array(c(v1,v2,v3), dim = c(R,R,R))

# 2) Fill the array

for (i in 1:R)
    for (j in 1:R)
        for (k in 1:R)
            AR[i,j,k] <- sample(1:3,1)

#print(AR)
library(plotly)
library(htmlwidgets)


fig <-plot_ly(showscale = FALSE)

#Try to create the fig with a loop

for (k in 1:R)
{                                   # Abre ciclo for.

s <- AR[,,k] + 10*k
print(s)

fig <- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~s)

}                                   # Cierra ciclo for.


fig
```

But obtain just the graph of the last added surface. Can you tell me please where is the mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are a victim of *lazy evaluation*. (See, for example, [here](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Functions.html).]  `for` loops use lazy evaluation so your index , `k`, is evaluated only when `fig` needs to be evaluated, which happens when you print `fig`.  At this point, `k` equals `R`, and so you get `R` copies of the same surface, overlaid on each other.

You need to `force` evaluation.  One way to do this is with `lapply`, which forces evaluation by default.

For example,

```
lapply(
  1:R,
  function(k) {                                   # Abre ciclo for.
    s <- AR[,,k] + 10*k
    print(s)
    fig <<- fig %>% add_surface(z = ~s)
  }  
)

# Cierra ciclo for.
fig
```

[Note the use of `<<-`.]  Giving

[image]